# Стоит ли сейчас абзацы обертывать в тег

Tags: html, css, seo

Стоить ли в статьях, абзацы обертывать в тег

```html
<p>Текст</p>
```

Тогда когда для отображения, для отображения всех переносов и отступов. Достаточно на блок выставить свойство

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

И все обзацы и тд, сохраняться, не будет только обертки по обзацам

На сео, ранжирование тег P влияет?

Comment: Сказывается ли это на продвижении, ранжировании?

Comment: Переносы строк — это не абзацы, у них разный семантический смысл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не стоит если в них нету текста или нужного контента. Это называеться мусорные теги. (Теги которые используют для декора страницы, но не содержат контента) Вы, можете не закрывать теги, на seo метрики это [ни влияет](https://html5book.ru/neobyazatelnye-tegi-html5/), если у вас страница на HTML5.

Если же для вас важно что бы текст нормально парсился ботами, то да. Наличие тега помагает.